# 404 Not Found disable error.log for CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I would like to know if it was possible to stop writing on the error.log file each time someone have a 404 Not Found page.

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you running, specifically? Logging capabilities vary substantially between versions.

Comment: https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/master/docs/Error/ErrorHandler.md#improved-version-of-errorhandler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CakePHP 3.x the error handler config has an option for exception classnames that should not be logged.

> `skipLog` - array - An array of exception classnames that should not be logged. This is useful to remove NotFoundExceptions or other common, but uninteresting log messages.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html